# java getRuntime exec dont catch another java program's input, give unknown source error

Tags: java, input, runtime, exec, call

I have some problems about getRuntime exec command. I used this command for calling another java program like that

```
import java.util.*;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        double x = -1;
        Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (x < 0) {
            System.out.println("assign negative number");
            x = klavye.nextDouble();
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println("x is positive, the program finished!");

    }
}
```

And I save this program like main.class with cmd and javac command. Then, I use second method for calling this program in another java class like that;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

/**
 *
 * @author kozmos
 */
public class runWithJava implements Runnable {

    public runWithJava(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
        istrm_ = istrm;
        ostrm_ = ostrm;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private final OutputStream ostrm_;
    private final InputStream istrm_;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] command = {"cmd",};
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        new Thread(new runWithJava(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
        new Thread(new runWithJava(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();

        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
        stdin.println("java main > mainOutput.txt");

        // write any other commands you want here
        stdin.close();
        //int returnCode = p.waitFor();
        //System.out.println("Return code = " + returnCode);*/
    }

}
```

But if i want to take input like main class i take error such that

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Unknown Source)
```

However, all other java programs work well such that don't need to input with scanner or buffered input. Is there any solution for taking input with getRuntime exec for according to another java program input?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the reason for the exception is there is a mismatch between the input that the child program expects, and the input you actually send/

Here's where you send the input:

```
stdin.println("java main > mainOutput.txt");
```

Here's where you read it:

```
Scanner klavye = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("assign negative number");
x = klavye.nextDouble();
System.out.println(x);
```

That will try to read `"java"` as a `double`.

You should be doing something like this:

```
stdin.println("1234.56");
```

or

```
stdin.println("-42.0");
stdin.println("1234.56");
```

Moving past that, you should not create multiple `Scanner` objects to read `System.in` in the child program.  Create just one before the loop and reuse it.

---

By the way "Unknown Source" is not an error.  It is merely saying that the JVM is unable to give you source file name and line number information because you are using a JRE without debug information.

The real error is `java.util.NoSuchElementException` and it is happening because it cannot read the next token as a `double` ... like your code asked it to do.

Comment: there is no difference i tried your said. I think when i write stdin.println("java main > mainOutput.txt") this try the finish at one time. When try to interact user give error.

Comment: And i dont understand how can i which variable related which scanner input when i don't see another java program.

Comment: *"And i dont understand how can i which variable related which scanner input when i don't see another java program."* - I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: You are right of typing error. 
I wrote stdin.println("-42.0") and parse in child program to double. That is work fine but don't take input from user, we give that "-42.0". We can write Scanner before stdin.println() and take from user after that assign number. But, we don't know what is the child program. We don't know how many input need according to loop. How can we decide when child programs need input?
Thanks for related in question:)

Comment: "And i dont understand how can i which variable related which scanner input when i don't see another java program." I tried to say we know child program for this example. But i want to make a class it works for all child program. So, i cannot check what is the child program, is need input or not. I have to decide that in master class but how?

Comment: *"I have to decide that in master class but how?"* - You can't.  It is not possible.

Comment: :( I try to something take child program and add more code such that change another txt file when see adding and i check master class this txt. But i can't update this before stdin.close(); if i update this txt before stdin.close(), i can solve maybe